# Compute Module Starter Kit - Initial Boot Issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I got my rapsberry pi compute module kit.

Unbox everything and inserted the Compute Module 3 on SO-DIMM connector of the IO Board.

J4 is set to EN
J3 is set to 3V3 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04 as host pc.

```
sudo apt-get install libusb-1.0-0-dev
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/raspberrypi/usbboot
cd usbboot
make
./rpiboot -v
```

This is end up at **Cannot open file fixup.dat**

What could be the problem !! Please help me

Comment: execute as sudo

Comment: yes, I try it with sudo also but same result.

Comment: You could delete everything and run it back on the raspberry.

Comment: Host need to be raspberry pi for this  ?

Comment: If you are going to compile in a certain architecture it will be compatible for that architecture unless you implement a cross-compiler.